# How vulnarable is php session

Tags: php, session

Its seems that the rumor outside is saying that php session key is not so secure.

At [some forum](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?873028-Discussion-The-PHP-Session-ID-is-Vulnrable-to-Brute-Force-Attack) says that php keys only 32bits so easy to be brute forced. While I've seen somewhere else(forgotten place) that say php use IP,time created, lotsa things to create a 160bits session keys.

so...I'm confused. Is it okay to use native session key cause I'm kinda hoping to run my site ASAP however if its so vulnarable it takes some times for me to do some more research.

How vulnarable for brute-forcing, etc way?

Comment: "I noticed that the session key is only 32 bits long" -- that's incorrect. You may interrupt your reading after these words.

Comment: PS: what if you read not only the first comment there but 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: There are [attacks](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-12/Briefings/Argyros/BH_US_12_Argyros_PRNG_WP.pdf) against versions below 5.3 that rely on flaws in the random number generator.

Comment: Oh I get what you mean now

Comment: So you mean that the php version above 5.3 is a new PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP session id is created using a MD5 hash with random input. MD5 is a 16 byte result (or 32 characters of hexadecimal numbers), or 128 bits. Not 32 bits.

If you don't like the security of default autogenerated session ids, you can:

1. configure [session.hash_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function) to use SHA-1 instead, giving you 160 bits.
2. create a session id yourself from cryptographically random sources and set the session id with a call to `session_id("your-random-value")`. Note that not every character is allowed for any session save handler, you might be restricted.

With that info, I think it is safe to conclude that PHP session ids are secure.

Comment: It's not completely random input: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L308